discord.py 2.4.0: Saving data, when closing modal
How can I make sure that, after closing a modal window, the entered data in it is saved when it is opened again?
I reviewed the entire discord.py documentation about modals, but I still couldn’t find how to do it...
Here the code, please help me!
class SupportApplicationModal(ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Apply for Support")

        self.add_item(ui.TextInput(
            label="Name and age",
            placeholder="Enter your name and age"
        ))
        self.add_item(ui.TextInput(
            label="Do you have an experience in this sphere?",
            placeholder="If yes, please tell us in more detail...",
            style=discord.TextStyle.long,
            max_length=150
        ))
        self.add_item(ui.TextInput(
            label="What device can you use for work?",
            placeholder="PC / Phone"
        ))
        self.add_item(ui.TextInput(
            label="Is your microphone good?",
            placeholder="Yes / No"
        ))

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="New application for Support",
            description=(
                f"**1) User applied:**\n{interaction.user.mention}\n\n"
                f"**2) Name and age:**\n```{self.children[0].value}```\n"
                f"**3) Does he had an experience?:**\n```{self.children[1].value}```\n"
                f"**4) Device using:**\n```{self.children[2].value}```\n"
                f"**5) Microphone presence:**\n```{self.children[3].value}```\n"
            )
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            "Thank you for **applying for Support**! We will try to review it **as soon as possible**. :)",
            ephemeral=True
        )
        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(1278424511489773599)
        await channel.send(content=f"<@&{ALLOWED_SUPPORT_TO_MANAGE}>", embed=embed)

class MainRoleSelectView(ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
    
    @ui.select(
        placeholder="Select the role",
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Support",
                description="Select and fill an application for Support",
                emoji="<:support:1288778117917179995>"
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Moderator",
                description="Select and fill an application for Moderator",
                emoji="<:moderator:1288778357202489345>"
            )],
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1
)
    async def select_role(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: ui.Select):
        selected_role = select.values[0]
        if selected_role == "Support":
            await interaction.response.send_modal(SupportApplicationModal())
        elif selected_role == "Moderator":
            await interaction.response.send_modal(ModeratorApplicationModal())

        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        select.values.clear()
        await interaction.edit_original_response(view=self)


I just want entered data to persist after closing a modal window in Discord. And when you opened it again, the entered data remained in its fields.

The method to achieve your goal is:

Store the data that users enter in the fields in the on_submit method;
Before sending the modal again to users, search for the values ​​saved for them;
Use these values ​​to fill in the default attribute of your fields TextImput.

